# Difference between contains() predicate testing in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

How can one explain the difference between these two XPath expressions?

**Expression 1:**

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Test')]
```

**Expression 2:**

```
//div[@class[contains(.,'Test')]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference<sup>1</sup>.  In all versions of XPath, including XPath 1.0, both XPaths will select exactly the same set of nodes for all XML documents:   *All `div` elements with a `@class` attribute whose string value contains `'Test'`.*

Use the first form; it's both shorter and more idiomatic.

---

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> Unless the XPath being evaluated in the context of a host language that supports XPath 2.0 schema-aware type information -- see [Michael Kay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43052965/290085).</sub>

Comment: For the record, will both expressions work in XPath 1? Or does one of the two only work in XPath 2?

Comment: Both will work the same in all versions of XPath, including XPath 1.0.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a difference, but a very subtle one. If your expression is an XPath 2.0 schema-aware expression, and @class is defined in the schema as list-valued, and if there is more than one item in the list, then `//div[contains(@class, 'Test')]` will fail with a type error, while `//div[@class[contains(.,'Test')]]` will return true if and only if one of the items has `Test` as a substring.

Comment: Is schema-awareness defined at the XPath (2.0 or other) level independent of XSLT?

Comment: XPath 2.0 is defined to handle both typed (i.e. schema-validated) and untyped data, but leaves it to host languages (like XSLT) to define subsets of the language with different levels of capability.

Answer (score 0):

Expression 1:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Test')]
```

1. current context node is `div` tag
2. `[]` is filter to get special `div` tag
3. `contains(@class, 'Test')` is a string function that return a `bool` value `True` or `False`, it will convert the parameter to its string value. The attribute's string value is its text.so the XPath is: **select all the div tag when it's class attribute evaluated to True.**

Expression 2:

```
//div[@class[contains(.,'Test')]]
```

1. current context node is `div` tag
2. `[]` is filter to get special `div` tag
3. in the filter, the current context node is the attribute node `class`,

`[contains(.,'Test')]` will filter the class attribute with string value `Test`. The left part is `//div[filtered class node]`, so the XPath became: **select all the div tag with those filtered class attribute.**